# Content Porter Error for Images and PDFs

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2013

I am importing content using content porter and getting following errors for images and pdf files.

**Invalid value for property 'BinaryContent'. Neither value for UploadFromFile property nor UploadFromStream is provided for itemBinaryContentmsgNeitherUploadFilenameNorStreamIsProvided**

What could be the issue.

Comment: could you specify which version of tridion you are using, and which version of content porter ?

Comment: Content Porter 2013 and Tridion 2011 HR2

Answer (score 1):

I see in the CP2013 manual that for use with Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1, a hotfix must be installed (Hotfix 79773). Can you confirm this is installed?

Other than that, can you import other types of multimedia items ?

Maybe you should have a look if there are any other warnings in your content porter log - you should be able to find the log on the machine where CP client is running, in folder C:\Users(user-id)\Documents\Content Porter\Logs, or on the server (check in your CP settings for the exact location)